# EFI unstable bootloader

Tags: uefi, bootloader, gpt

I am running (or trying to) Ubuntu 15.04 on my Toshiba Satellite Radius 11. In case you're unfamiliar with the Toshiba Satellite Radius 11, it is EFI and has a GPT hard drive. I boot into the live USB and install Ubuntu using the default "Erase hard disk and install Ubuntu" option. I reboot and it usually boots.

However, it is incredibly "fragile". For example, if the computer force shuts down, then the bootloader appears damaged, and the computer throws an error that it had nothing to boot into. To fix this, I need to boot into the Ubuntu live USB and run Boot Repair. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to edit your `/etc/fstab` file so that the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) mounts read-only, or even not at all. (You could set it so that it doesn't auto-mount, but can be mounted manually.) This will limit operations that involve updating the boot loader on the ESP, but those are few and far between -- mostly just GRUB updates. The idea behind this suggestion is that your uncontrolled shutdown may be leaving the ESP's FAT filesystem in a state to which your firmware objects. Mounting it read-only, or not at all, should prevent such problems from occurring. The big risk to this approach is that if you fail to mention a GRUB update, it won't be written properly to the ESP. In a worst-case scenario, the system might fail to boot; but a more likely scenario is that you'll continue to boot with an outdated GRUB.

Another suggestion is to prepare and learn better tools for recovery. You can put my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a CD-R or USB flash drive and keep it ready. If this problem recurs, you could then use rEFInd to boot into Ubuntu, thus bypassing the need to boot a recovery disk. That might be enough to get it to boot correctly on the next reboot; and if not, you might be able to use `efibootmgr` to re-register GRUB with the firmware, if it's forgotten that. You'll need to learn to use some new tools, and figure out precisely what's happening that's causing your boot to fail, but the end result should be a quicker and easier recovery than running Boot Repair from an emergency disk.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Apparently it helps if it is actually installed to the ESP and not to some other random place where it'll be deleted next time you do anything irregular.

Rock solid now, installed nice and secure to "/dev/sda1".